# Filesorter alternative

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, uti

I found a really cool app in the App Store called [FileSorter](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/filesorter/id411279149?mt=12)

It automatically sort files. Is there any FREE alternative?

Comment: Uh, that application appears to be currently free already.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that application *is* free.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this site a little while ago that let's me see if there are alternatives to apps either because they're on Windows (and the app's not important enough to boot Parallels) or too expensive:
[alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/)

Give that a try and see what you can find.
Specifically for you, this is what I found [there](http://alternativeto.net/SearchResult.aspx?profile=all&platform=all&search=file+sorter).